# dataSource.getItemId(position) returns null

Tags: android, listview, cursor, android-listview

I'm trying to get the database id of a ListView member so that I can pass it to a new activity but the .getItemId(position) method of SimpleCursorAdapter is returning null, instead of the _id from the database.  It was my understanding that this should return the _id field grabbed by the cursor, but it's not working out for me.  Would love some suggestions

```
DatabaseHelper helper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    database = helper.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor data = database.query("myDb", fields, null, null, null, null, null);
    dataSource = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.row, data, fields, new int[] {R.id.idText, R.id.castName, R.id.castDescription});
    data.moveToFirst();

    final ListView view = getListView();

    view.setHeaderDividersEnabled(true);
    view.addHeaderView(getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.row, null));
    setListAdapter(dataSource);


    database.close();

    view.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

          @Override
          public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {


            // Prepare intent
        Intent newActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ItemIdTester.class);
            newActivity.putExtra("itemId",dataSource.getItemId(position));

            // start activity
            startActivity(newActivity);
          }
        });
```

Comment: does R.id.idText have the _id mapped?

Comment: yes, the text gets properly populated, as far as i can tell

Comment: what fields are you querying for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The adapter was returning null because of the headers added by

```
view.setHeaderDividersEnabled(true);
view.addHeaderView(getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.row, null));
```

I also started getting my data directly from the cursor.  Here is the full onItemClickListener that fixed the issue

```
view.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

          @Override
          public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {

            Cursor cursor = (Cursor) dataSource.getItem(position-1);

            Long itemId = cursor.getLong(0);  
            // Prepare intent
            Intent newActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CastrRecorder.class);
            newActivity.putExtra("itemId",itemId.toString());
            // start activity
            startActivity(newActivity);
          }
        });
```

Comment: Why the addHeaderView made the adapter returns null?

Comment: The header is the first index in the list.  Since that record wasn't in the DB, dataSource.getItemId(position) couldn't execute properly to retrieve the _id from the DB cursor.